# Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'assets/res.zip' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Tags: flutter, archive

I'm trying to extract files from an archive but I'm getting this error.

> E/flutter (31571): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'assets/res.zip' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

My code.
https://pub.dev/packages/archive/example

```
final bytes = File('assets/res.zip').readAsBytesSync();
final archive = ZipDecoder()
    .decodeBytes(bytes, verify: true, password: '123');

// Extract the contents of the Zip archive to disk.
for (final file in archive) {
  final filename = file.name;
  if (file.isFile) {
    final data = file.content as List<int>;
    File('out/' + filename)
      ..createSync(recursive: true)
      ..writeAsBytesSync(data);
  } else {
    Directory('out/' + filename).create(recursive: true);
  }
}
```

---

pubspec.yaml

```
 assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/res.zip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the asset first from the bundled binary. For this, use the [`rootBundle`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/rootBundle.html).

> The [rootBundle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/rootBundle.html) contains the resources that were packaged with the application when it was built. To add resources to the [rootBundle] for your application, add them to the `assets` subsection of the `flutter` section of your application's `pubspec.yaml` manifest.

Here's an example:

```dart
final byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/res.zip');
final buffer = byteData.buffer;
final archive = ZipDecoder()
    .decodeBytes(buffer.asUint8List(), verify: true, password: '123');

// ...
```

Another approach could be extracting the asset to a temp folder like the following:

```dart
final byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/res.zip');
final buffer = byteData.buffer;
File file = await File('/path/to/extract/res.zip').writeAsBytes(
    buffer.asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));
final bytes = File('/path/to/extract/res.zip').readAsBytesSync();
final archive =
    ZipDecoder().decodeBytes(bytes, verify: true, password: '123');

// ...
```

To get the `/path/to/extract/` path, for example the temp folder, use the plugin [`path_provider`](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) and the function [`getTemporaryDirectory`](https://pub.dev/documentation/path_provider/latest/path_provider/getTemporaryDirectory.html).

> Path to the temporary directory on the device that is not backed up and is suitable for storing caches of downloaded files.